# PHP mysqli INSERT does nothing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-insert

**I looked at a dozen questions and nothing helps.** Some give contradictory advice.

I have a simple INSERT INTO query with PHP mysqli. The query and the connection are both ok, and the query actually executes on an older version of xampp. But when I switched to a newer one - nothing! No errors, but, no new data, either.

```
<?php 

    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "standard_user", "standard", "liquidity");
    if (!$connection) {
        die("Error: ".mysqli_connect_errno());
    }
    $table = "clan";
    $username = "someusername";
    $ime = "My name";

    $query = "INSERT INTO ";
    $query.=$table;
    $query.=" (username, ime) ";
    $query.="VALUES ('".$username."','".$ime."');";

    //$query = "INSERT INTO clan (username, ime) VALUES ('someusername', 'My name')";

    mysqli_query($connection, $query);

    if ($query) {
        echo("Success: ".$ime);
    } else {
        echo("There has been an error. Try again.");
    }
    mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

This is the query it echoed when I tried it: `INSERT INTO clan (username, ime) VALUES ('someusername','My name');`

Since every time I reload it prints "Success: My name", I guess it somehow executes. But, no data is saved. I can't figure it out. Any help?

[**SOLUTION**] The `clan` table had a foreign key (`username`) to another table which had no entries, so there was nothing wrong with the query, but a silly overlook actually. Thanks to Deivison Francisco's answer, it was easy to determine the cause of the problem by simply reading an error.

Comment: check the `mysqli_query($connection, $query)` return, pls

Comment: `$query` is a string containing your query. it is **NOT** the return value from `mysqli_query()`. in other words, you're checking the WRONG value for success/failure. `$result = mysqli_query(...); if (!$result) { die(mysqli_error($connection)); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the return value of mysqli_query() to determine the result.
Also think about using prepared statements to mitigate SQL Injections.

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if ($result) {
    echo("Success: ".$ime);
} else {
    echo("There has been an error. Try again. Error message: ".mysqli_error($connection));
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Not just to me, though. Now it prints "There has been an error..." part. But still no idea why. As I said, it did actually work.

Comment: I edited my answer so that it also prints the error message

Answer (score 2):

Alter for:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO clan (username, ime) VALUES ('someusername', 'My name')";
$return = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if ($return) {
    echo("Success: ".$ime);
} else {
    echo("There has been an error. Try again.");
}
mysqli_close($connection);
```